# xcodebuild: error: './*****.xcworkspace' is not a workspace file

Tags: macos, jenkins, fastlane, xcodebuild, jenkins-agent

We are running a Jenkins-master on Windows Server with an iOS Job, which runs on a MacOS slave. The slave was running well on MacOS Yosemite but after upgrading to El Capitan, the build was broken.

The issue is that xcodebuild does not recognize our workspace file anymore: `xcodebuild: error: './*****.xcworkspace' is not a workspace file.`

When I execute this command from the command line with the Jenkins user, it succeeds.

Has anyone an idea how we can solve this issue?

It seems that xcodebuild can see the file because otherwise, it would say that ****.xcworkspace was not found.
We could only reproduce this issue, when ****.xcworkspace is a file and not a directory

We also checked permissions and encoding. I made also exact same clean setups of Yosemite and El Capitan. Yosemite works, and El Capitan does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was obvious an strange bug with El Capitan. After the upgrade to mac os sierra, it worked again.